# How to set "Notification sound" on by default? [Android app]

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've published an android application recently, But for some reason when someone download the app from the play store, the Notification Sound is turned off, How can I force that when downloading the app, the notification sound will be turned on by default ?

Edit:
The main problem is, When I send a push notification, no sound will be heard because the "**Sound Notification**" in the setting of the app is turned off, So in order to let the sound go, I need to allow that myself by changing the app's setting. Any way how to make notification sound turned on by default?

Answer (score 0):

This is highly dependant on the device and it's OS but you can set the sound to play as 'default', the issue is this ultimately comes down to the device's settings and silence mode which overrides anything you may do.

```json
{
    "to" : "device:token",

    "notification" : {
      "body" : "Great Example!",
      "title" : "Cool Title",
      "icon" : "icon",
      "sound" : "default"
    }
  }
```

> When your app is in the background, Android directs notification messages to the system tray. A user tap on the notification opens the app launcher by default. This includes messages that contain both notification and data payload. In these cases, the notification is delivered to the device's system tray, and the data payload is delivered in the extras of the intent of your launcher Activity.